# MySQL thread_concurrency, innodb_thread_concurrency, should I use or not?

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I have a dedicated server with 24 CPUs and 32GB of ram.

This server serves website and mysql.

I don't know what is the difference between those two variables, if there is any.

I don't know if I should use them because after reading on Google some say that those variables might be ignored depending on the OS or MySQL versión.

So should I use them?

Answer (score 4):

Please read [Mysql Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/) carefully, select decent initial values, monitor performance of your server during busy hours of the day and tune accordingly.

There are no simple answers, because your workload is uniquely yours.

Off the top of my head your balance of CPU and RAM seems wrong. I think 1~4 cores for 64GB of ram, or 24 cores for max ram you can get, 192GB perhaps? CPU needs to be provisioned for query rate, while RAM for active/hot dataset size. I can imagine a weird workload where your CPU/RAM makes sense, but I'm not sure innodb is in fact the best solution for such workload.

Coming back to your question: ["thread concurrency doesn't do what you expect"](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/06/04/thread_concurrency-doesnt-do-what-you-expect/) in short most likely you should not use. [innodb_thread_concurrency](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/12/02/kernel_mutex-problem-cont-or-triple-your-throughput/) is just a cutoff, I'd say if your workload is all hot (i.e. mysql doesn't use much disk(?)), it should not be higher than number of cores. Do read up the blog, these settings are not as simple as they seem.

Also you may want to pay attention to: thread cache, innodb buffer pool, add mem pool, heap table size, sort/key buffer size, flush log at tx commit, log file size. And probably a few more I couldn't think of right now.

Answer (score 4):

The thread_concurrency option in MySQL is mainly for Solaris systems and will also be depreciated in version 5.6, so tuning it might be a waste of time.

```
thread_concurrency
```

Also please read: https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/06/04/thread_concurrency-doesnt-do-what-you-expect/

The innodb_thread_concurrency can be adjusted for performance, but I've found no performance increases using it.

I found the best information from https://www.percona.com/blog/. All others suggesting and giving advice might deem MySQL inoperable.

Answer (score 2):

(According to manual "thread_concurrency" variable is usable only for Solaris OS)

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on a number of issues, the operating system, the scheduler options, the I/O subsystem, and the number and type of CPUs, as well as the type and number of queries being run.

The only way you can tell for certain on your system is to adjust the value of innodb_thread_concurrency and run typical workloads to benchmark.  A reasonable starting point is from 0 to 48 (in your case) x2 times the number of CPU cores available.  You could then increase this until the point at which you start to see the system become CPU bound and throttle it back a bit.

This doesn't take into account the disk activity that your transactions will generate, From there you can then look at disk I/O and make adjustments from there.

Setting this to 0 is setting this to unlimited 
** so that by default there is no limit on the number of concurrently executing threads

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-performance-thread_concurrency.html